# NotNullViolation on FactoryGirl.create with has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, factory-bot

I'm having a problem where I get a Null violation error while calling create on my Factory.

Here's my two models:

```
# Table name: test_masters
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
class TestMaster < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :test_slave, dependent: :destroy
end

# Table name: test_slave
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  test_master_id :integer          not null
class TestSlave < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test_master, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And the following factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :test_master do
    test_slave
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :test_slave do
  end
end
```

When I run FactoryGirl.create(:test_master) in the rails console I get the following errors:

```
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "test_master_id" violates not-null constraint
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "test_master_id" violates not-null constraint
```

I thought calling the test_slave factory from the test_master factory would automatically provide the test_master_id... but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Is there something wrong with my factories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `test_slave` factory should define the attributes it needs to create valid records. Since your `TestSlave` requires a `TestMaster`, you need to define that in the `test_slave` factory.

In short, you are specifying the association in your factories in the wrong direction. Try this instead:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :test_master do
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :test_slave do
    test_master
  end
end
```

Then, when you do `FactoryGirl.create(:test_slave)`, you can either specify its `TestMaster`:

```
master = FactoryGirl.create(:test_master)
FactoryGirl.create(:test_slave, test_master: test_master)
```

or it will generate one for you if don't specify that attribute:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:test_slave) # Generates a new TestMaster and uses that.
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding a way of creating a master factory with a default slave using the after build callback... (while keeping theunraveler's solution as well)
The following factories now give me enough of the flexibility I need in my specs:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :test_master do
    factory :test_master_with_slave do
      after(:build) do |master|
        master.test_slave = FactoryGirl.build(:test_slave,
                                              test_master: master)
      end
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :test_slave do
    test_master
  end
end
```

(theunraveler, thanks for the alternate solution.  It pointed me in the right direction.)